# Get more decimals in complex python division

Tags: python, numpy, decimal, complex-numbers

I'm using the division obtained from using

```
from __future__ import division
```

in Python 2.7, and I'm using the complex numbers in Python.
I want to get more decimals from the division of complex numbers. Does exists a way to do this? I know the decimal.Decimal command, but it needs to receive the numbers before, and it doesn't get complex numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the gmpy2 library. It provides fast arbitrary precision integer, real, and complex arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still `decimal.Decimal`. But you'll need to use two of them per complex number, and you'll have to implement the math operations yourself. Fortunately there are plenty of references for the basic complex operations.

Comment: But to make it I will have to edit all my code for that, and are various names to re-edit. There isn't another way?

Comment: Sounds like you're lucky that Python supports both OOP and defining operators.